# Network icon disappears from panel 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, unity, network-manager, applet

The network icon in top panel disappears for me. Mostly when I suspend and resume the PC after some time. I use 16.04 + Unity DE

I am aware of the thread that exists for v 12.04. I tried using commands

1. `sudo service network-manager restart`
2. `nm-applet`

Now, the good thing is, after typing these commands in succession, the network icon is back for me. But, if I close the terminal, icon disappears again.

How to fix this ? Help, please..

**Update** :

If it helps, terminal shows this

> $ nm-applet
>
> (nm-applet:12826): nm-applet-WARNING **: Cannot grab information for
>   modem at /hfp/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_63_E5_45_6B_50: Not found
>
> (nm-applet:12826): nm-applet-WARNING **: Cannot grab information for
>   modem at /hfp/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_63_E5_45_6B_50: Not found
>
> (nm-applet:12826): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not available
>   for modem at /hfp/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_63_E5_45_6B_50

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was able to resolve it by removing the state and restarting the network-manager.

`sudo service network-manager stop`

`sudo rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state`

`sudo service network-manager start`